# Why would this arrow function work?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I am exploring arrow functions, I came up with this basic example, I just need to understand how the follwing works

```
var getServer = () => {
    if(document.getElementById('server')){
        var serverHTML = document.getElementById('server');
        serverHTML.innerHTML = "Server: " + window.location.host;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('serverxs')){
        var serverHTMLxs = document.getElementById('serverxs');
        serverHTMLxs.innerHTML = "Server: " + window.location.host;
    }
};
```

The `getServer = () =>` part is confusing how is empty brackets correct? Or am I wrong.

Any documentation or answers appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "read" arrow functions like this

```
(par1, par2) => "value"
```

turns into

```
function(par1, par2){ return "value"; }
```

So:

```
() =>
```

turns into a function with no parameters passed to it.
An exception to this is when one argument is passed to an arrow function, so:

```
param=>{ return value; }
// turns into
function(param){ return value; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a function ***without parameters***, as short/arrow function:

```
var getServer = () => { /* ... */ }
// matches
var getServer = function (){ /* ... */}

// Example:
var example = function (foo, bar){ return foo;}
// matches
var example = (foo, bar) => { return foo;}
```

[There are some caveats though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch), which you might want to check.

Comment: * with all the caveats described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Comment: I've added it to my post so it gets read better :) For simple functions they're the same, but it might get confusing fast.

Comment: I tried using it in one of my projects but the arguments got a little confusing